# How can I preview large images quickly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file

Hi I am making a mobile web application that requires a user to upload multiple images on to the server. Once they select their images, I want to show a thumbnail preview of their images before they choose to upload to the server. I have tried both FileReader way and the createObjectURL (using a canvas) and both methods take ages for the images to appear. This normally would not be an issue but most images on a mobile phone are high quality and are at least 2-3mb.

The time it takes for the thumbnails to generate is almost the same as actually uploading the image. Is there any way I can just show an instant low res preview of the images before uploading?

The following are two ways that I have used to try and preview images:

**createObjectURL and Canvas way**

```
<input type="file" id="browseImages" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*">
<output id="list"></output>
```

---

```
document
  .getElementById("browseImages")
  .addEventListener("change", handleFileSelect, true);

function handleFileSelect(evt) {
  var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

  // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
  for (var i = 0, f; (f = files[i]); i++) {
    // Only process image files.
    if (!f.type.match("image.*")) {
      continue;
    }

    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = 110;
    canvas.height = 100;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 100, 100);
    };
    img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(f);
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(canvas);
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(f);
  }
}
```

The above way reads the images that the user selected and creates a canvas with the image for each image that was selected.

**FileReader way**

```
<input type="file" id="browseImages" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*">
<output id="list"></output>
```

---

```
document
  .getElementById("browseImages")
  .addEventListener("change", handleFileSelect, true);

function handleFileSelect(evt) {
  var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

  // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
  for (var i = 0, f; (f = files[i]); i++) {
    // Only process image files.
    if (!f.type.match("image.*")) {
      continue;
    }

    var reader = new FileReader();

    // Closure to capture the file information.
    reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
      return function(e) {
        // Render thumbnail.
        var span = document.createElement("span");
        span.innerHTML = [
          '<img style="height:75px;" src="',
          e.target.result,
          '" title="',
          escape(theFile.name),
          '"/>'
        ].join("");
        document.getElementById("list").insertBefore(span, null);
      };
    })(f);

    // Read in the image file as a data URL.
    reader.readAsDataURL(f);
  }
}
```

The above way uses a FileReader to read and then process the preview images.

Both these above methods take time going through each image, reading it and then processing a thumbnail. The speed of it is as if I am uploading the images. Is there any way I can generate instant thumbnails of the selected images? Bare in mind this is for a mobile browser, so it will not have a big memory like a PC.

Comment: Most smart phones should be able to deal with that load. At the same time, you are going to have to read the files somehow (every single bit) even if you want to generate a lower-quality thumbnail (btw, your first code is already generating lower quality thumbnails).

Comment: @HanletEscaño But the issue is that if I select 10-20 high res images then it takes ages (30-60 second minimum) to just generate a preview. That is going to put off the end user as more time will also be spent on actually uploading the images

Comment: I understand. What I mean is that I do not believe there is a way around that issue, because even to generate a preview, you need to read in (or rather the browser) every bit of that image.

Comment: I have no idea how this works but this library does what you want pretty fast in my opinion, maybe take a look at it: http://plugins.krajee.com/file-basic-usage-demo

Comment: @user2415266 Tried that on my smartphone with multiple high res images and its takes a similar time to my code

Comment: @Matt9Atkins did you find a solution for that?